# how to start using the framework foundation for sites and deploy the first project

Tags: zurb-foundation-6

I want start using the framework foundation for sites but after reading the DOCS (http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) I got confused:

- Why I should use a package manager to download a bunch of html, css and javascript file?
- Or is there something else in the pile?

I'm working on windows and I know what are more or less html, css and javascript, but I'm new to frontend framework.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new, I would recommend using [Yeti Launch](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/yeti-launch). Yeti Launch allows you to create a Foundation 6 project with a [Basic](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#basic-template) or [Advanced](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/starter-projects.html#zurb-template) template. The templates use a package manager with everything wired up for you.

With Yeti Launch you get the benefits of a build system (browser reloading, page templates, minification/concatenation, include only the components you use, autoprefixes, etc.) and you don't have to use the command line if you're not comfortable with it.

Comment: Are there a lot sub-tool to understand with this build system?

Comment: If you use the basic template, no, but you will be lacking in the features I listed. The main thing you need to know for the Advanced/Zurb template is the page template system Panini: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/panini.html

Answer (score 1):

Download foundation first here [complete-f6.zip](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/download/assets/complete-f6.zip). Then use `foundation.min.css` and `foundation.min.js` (of course include jquery.js) on your page and you're free to use whatever is in the foundation docs.